# TypeError: Object of type 'complex' is not JSON serializable while using pyLDAvis.display() function

Tags: json, gensim, serializable

I have a document Term matrix with nine documents:

[image]

I am running the code as below:

```
import pyLDAvis.gensim
topicData = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(ldamodel, docTermMatrix, dictionary)
pyLDAvis.display(topicData)
```

I am getting the below error when executing pyLDAvis.display function:

> TypeError: Object of type 'complex' is not JSON serializable

Can someone guide here? What could be the reason?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. Following the GH issue referenced by user3411846 I found a different, simpler solution.

The complex number had come from coordinate calculation and specifying the "mds" worked.

https://github.com/bmabey/pyLDAvis/issues/69#issuecomment-311337191

So your code would be

```
topicData = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(ldamodel, docTermMatrix, dictionary, mds='mmds')
```

Other options for mds are here: https://pyldavis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/API.html#pyLDAvis.prepare

Comment: similarly, i set `mds='tsne'`, which also solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line of code to your pyLDAvis `pyLDAvis/utils.py`

```
    if np.iscomplexobj(obj):
        return abs(obj)
```

This error has been reported in GitHub  [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/bmabey/pyLDAvis/issues/69)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your pyldavis/utils.py (NumPyEncoder)
if np.iscomplexobj(obj):
return abs(obj)

class NumPyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
def default(self, obj):
if isinstance(obj, np.int64) or isinstance(obj, np.int32):
return int(obj)
if isinstance(obj, np.float64) or isinstance(obj, np.float32):
return float(obj)
if np.iscomplexobj(obj):
return abs(obj)
return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

#resolved my issue